# Can't add text next to divs

Tags: html, css

I've been trying to add some text next to an image but I can't get it working, it seems like "faces" style doesn't allow me to, do you know what's wrong? :)

I have:

```
<div class="teams-body" id="teams-body">
<div class="faces">
<img src="http://assets.lolesports.com/player/lourlo-iatd1lge.png">
Lorem ipsumdolor sit amet consectetur adipiscing elit 
</div>
<div class="faces"> 
<img src="http://assets.lolesports.com/player/iwdominate-4kjr1rn6.png">
Lorem ipsumdolor sit amet consectetur adipiscing elit 
</div>
<div class="faces">
<img src="http://assets.lolesports.com/player/fenix-6cyhqz7w.png">
Lorem ipsumdolor sit amet consectetur adipiscing elit
</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.faces {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    -webkit-border-radius: 50%;
    -moz-border-radius: 50%;
    -ms-border-radius: 50%;
    -o-border-radius: 50%;
    border-radius: 50%;
    z-index: -1;
}


.faces img {
    display: inline;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #79b9e1;
    z-index: -1;
}
```

It currently looks like:

> [img]
>
> [img]
>
> [img]

I want it to look like:

> [img] Lorem ipsumdolor sit amet consectetur adipiscing elit Lorem ipsumdolor sit amet consectetur adipiscing elit
>   [img] Lorem ipsumdolor sit amet consectetur adipiscing elit Lorem ipsumdolor sit amet consectetur adipiscing elit

Comment: `width: 100%` for `.faces img` might be the issue because stretches the image to 100% of container width

Comment: Put your text in, say, a `span` and it should work if you have `<span><img><span><img>`

Comment: Overflow hidden is also an issue, no extra span required.

Comment: @sef4eg What may I use instead?

Comment: @Chris Tried but didn't work, did you mean: https://jsfiddle.net/mgqaszt0/ ?

Here's the Fiddle someone asked for: https://jsfiddle.net/szypw37g/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this maybe?

And if you want image/text vertically centered, add `vertical-align: middle;` to `.faces img` rule

```css
.faces {
  height: 100px;
  position: relative;
}


.faces img {
  height: 100%;
  width: auto;
  background-color: #79b9e1;
  border-radius: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div class="teams-body" id="teams-body">
  <div class="faces">
    <img src="http://assets.lolesports.com/player/lourlo-iatd1lge.png">
    Lorem ipsumdolor sit amet consectetur adipiscing elit 
  </div>
  <div class="faces"> 
    <img src="http://assets.lolesports.com/player/iwdominate-4kjr1rn6.png">
    Lorem ipsumdolor sit amet consectetur adipiscing elit 
  </div>
  <div class="faces">
    <img src="http://assets.lolesports.com/player/fenix-6cyhqz7w.png">
    Lorem ipsumdolor sit amet consectetur adipiscing elit
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

Use this code

```css
.faces img {
    display: inline;
    background-color: #79b9e1;
    z-index: -1;
  width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    -webkit-border-radius: 50%;
    -moz-border-radius: 50%;
    -ms-border-radius: 50%;
    -o-border-radius: 50%;
    border-radius: 50%;
    z-index: -1;
  vertical-align:middle
  
}
```

```html
<div class="teams-body" id="teams-body">
<div class="faces">
<img src="http://assets.lolesports.com/player/lourlo-iatd1lge.png">
Lorem ipsumdolor sit amet consectetur adipiscing elit 
</div>
<div class="faces"> 
<img src="http://assets.lolesports.com/player/iwdominate-4kjr1rn6.png">
Lorem ipsumdolor sit amet consectetur adipiscing elit 
</div>
<div class="faces">
<img src="http://assets.lolesports.com/player/fenix-6cyhqz7w.png">
Lorem ipsumdolor sit amet consectetur adipiscing elit
</div>
</div>
```